# How to enforce uniqueness of column on nested attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique-constraint, rails-activerecord

Lets say I had the following setup

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :house_color, :street_address
end
```

And for some reason, I wanted to only allow a given user to have one address of a given color.

How would I lock down? something like

```
   validates :address.house_color.unique
```

Except functional....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true
  validates_associated :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :house_color, street_address
  validates_uniqueness_of :house_color. :scope => :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use reject_if

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| Address.where(:house_color => attributes["house_color"], :user_id => attributes["users_id]).exists? }
```